# Elasticsearch "AND in query_string" vs. "default_operator AND"

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch v7.1.1

I dont understand the difference between a query_string containing "AND"
vs. "default_operator AND"

I thought it should yield the same result, but doesnt:

```
HTTP POST http://localhost:9200/umlautsuche

{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": ["ph => f"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_ngram": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_name_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "german_normalization"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "string_fields_german": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_name_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "dates": {
          "match": "lastModified",
          "match_pattern": "regex",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "date",
            "ignore_malformed": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
HTTP POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk

{ "index" : { "_index" : "umlautsuche", "_id" : "1" } }
{"vorname": "Stephan-Jörg", "nachname": "Müller", "ort": "Hollabrunn"}

{ "index" : { "_index" : "umlautsuche", "_id" : "2" } }
{"vorname": "Stephan-Joerg", "nachname": "Mueller", "ort": "Hollabrunn"}

{ "index" : { "_index" : "umlautsuche", "_id" : "3" } }
{"vorname": "Stephan-Jörg", "nachname": "Müll", "ort": "Hollabrunn"}
```

No results here - unexpected by me:

```
HTTP POST http://localhost:9200/umlautsuche/_search

{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Stefan Müller Jör*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "fields": ["vorname", "nachname"]
        }
    }
}
```

This query gives the results as expected by me:

```
HTTP POST http://localhost:9200/umlautsuche/_search

{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Stefan AND Müller AND Jör*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "fields": ["vorname", "nachname"]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I configure query/analyzer so I dont need these "AND" between my search terms?

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed configuration and example documents, it helped a lot. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are facing is an obscurity of boolean logic of [`query_string` boolean operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators), and possibly an undocumented behavior. Because of this obscurity I believe it is better to either use [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query with explicit logic, or to use a [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/copy-to.html).

Let me explain in a bit more detail what's going on and how can you fix it.

### Why doesn't the first query match?

In order to see how the query gets executed, let's set [`profile: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-profile.html):

```
POST /umlautsuche/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Stefan Müller Jör*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "fields": [
                "vorname",
                "nachname"
            ]
        }
    },
    "profile": true
}
```

In the ES response we will see:

```
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      {
        "id": "[QCANVs5gR0GOiiGCmEwj7w][umlautsuche][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BooleanQuery",
                "description": "+((+nachname:stefan +nachname:muller) | (+vorname:stefan +vorname:muller)) +(nachname:jor* | vorname:jor*)",
                "time_in_nanos": 17787641,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
```

We are interested in this part:

```
"+((+nachname:stefan +nachname:muller) | (+vorname:stefan +vorname:muller)) +(nachname:jor* | vorname:jor*)"
```

Without going into deep analysis, we can tell that this query wants to find documents with surname `stefan` and with surname `muller`, which is impossible (because `stefan` is never a surname among the documents).

What we actually want to do, I presume, is "find people whose full name is `Stefan Müller Jör*`". This is not what the query generated by Elasticsearch does.

### Why does the second query match?

Let's do the same trick with `explain: true`. The response would contain this:

```
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      {
        "id": "[QCANVs5gR0GOiiGCmEwj7w][umlautsuche][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BooleanQuery",
                "description": "+(nachname:stefan | vorname:stefan) +(nachname:muller | vorname:muller) +(nachname:jor* | vorname:jor*)",
                "time_in_nanos": 17970342,
                "breakdown": {
```

We can see that the query got interpreted like this:

```
"+(nachname:stefan | vorname:stefan) +(nachname:muller | vorname:muller) +(nachname:jor* | vorname:jor*)"
```

Which we can roughly interpret as "find people whose name or surname is one these three names", which is what we expect it to do.

In the documentation of [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) it says that with `default_operator: AND` it should interpret spaces as `AND`s:

> The default operator used if no explicit operator is specified. For
>   example, with a default operator of `OR`, the query `capital of Hungary`
>   is translated to `capital OR of OR Hungary`, and with default operator
>   of `AND`, the same query is translated to `capital AND of AND Hungary`.
>   The default value is `OR`.

Although, from what we have just seen, this does not seem to be correct - at least in case of querying multiple fields.

So what can we do about it?

### Use `bool` with explicit logic

This query seems to work:

```
POST /umlautsuche/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "Stefan Müller Jör*",
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "fields": [
                            "vorname"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "Stefan Müller Jör*",
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "fields": [
                            "nachname"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query is not an exact equivalent, consider it as an example. For instance, if we would have another record like this, without "Jörg":

```
{"vorname": "Stephan", "nachname": "Müll", "ort": "Hollabrunn"}
```

the `bool` query above would match it despite missing "Jörg". To overcome this you can write a more complex `bool` query, but this will not do if you wanted to avoid parsing user input.

How can we still use plain, unparsed query string?

### Introduce a `copy_to` field

We can try to use [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/copy-to.html) capability. It will copy the content of several fields into another field and will analyze these fields all together.

We will have to modify the mapping configuration (unfortunately the existing index will have to be recreated):

```
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "dynamic_templates": [
            {
        "name_fields_german": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*name",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_name_analyzer",
            "copy_to": "full_name"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "string_fields_german": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_name_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "dates": {
          "match": "lastModified",
          "match_pattern": "regex",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "date",
            "ignore_malformed": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then we can populate the index in exactly the same manner as we did before.

Now we can query the new field `full_name` with the following query:

```
POST /umlautsuche/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "Stefan Müller Jör*",
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "default_operator": "AND",
                        "fields": [
                            "full_name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query will return same 2 documents as the second query. Thus, in this case `default_operator: AND` behaves as we would expect it, asking for all tokens from the query to be matched.

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: wow thank you. I like "copy_to". tradeoff: I will loose my boosting feature "firstname^2 lastname^4 city^1 ..."